# Gh-pages, URL rewrite functionality to make SEO friendly urls

Tags: github, url-rewriting, jekyll, github-pages

I have a site hosted on gh-pages, 
I want to add the url rewrite functionality to make urls user friendly, I searched a lot about this and I came about the jekyll re-write plugin, can anyone help me on this re-write plugin?

Comment: Did you ever try to use this plugin ? Did you have a Github repository to diG in ?

Comment: Yes i have hosted my site on gh-pages. I did not use the jykll plugins.

Answer (score 3):

What is **the jekyll re-write plugin ?**

Jekyll is simple and SEO friendly.

- by default file name is used in url, up to you to name a file `23567KSDFG.html` or `3d-printing-get-scarlett-joahnonss-live-n++++-fu+++.html`
- you can also, in every page/post, add a `permalink: any-other/path/I-w0oot/`

No need for plugin to generate good SEO friendly urls.

Then, if you have to redirect some old pages from an old blog, you can use [jekyll-redirect-from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from).

So basically, what you need is only some good information architecture, file naming and good writing. Go with `front matter` and `layouts` this is definitely the way to go.